# Compare all elements of a singly linked list to each other (C++)

Tags: c++, for-loop, linked-list, comparison

I am trying to implement a function that compares all nodes of a singly linked list to each other.

For example, let's assume I have a linked list with eight nodes. (I don't have a count that tells me that however)

I need to compare 1 with 2,3,4,5,6,7 and 8. Then I need to compare 2 with 3,4,5,6,7, and 8. Obviously, I can't compare 1 with 1, 8 with 8, and 2 with 1 after 1 and 2 were already compared.

I know this is a double for-loop, but I am having a hard time structuring this.

Can anyone provide any insight or pseudocode?

I assume it's something like this:

```
//I know already that the list is NOT empty. But I don't know if it contains only one node.

Node * current = list;
Node * compWith;

if (current->next != NULL)
{
   for (current = list; current->next != NULL; current = current->next)
      for (compWith = current->next; compWith->next != NULL; compWith = compWith->next)
         //Compare here
}
```

However I am not entirely sure my loops are stopping at the correct time, and I think I'm doing double comparisons somewhere. Any insight or pseudocode?

Comment: You have this tagged as python, but you put C++ in your title...which is it?

Comment: This is C++. I am not sure where I tagged as Python? I'm getting used to this site's features still, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: BTW: the if before loop is not necesary, loop condition will work it out anyway...